# widget in sub-window update with real-time data in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I've tried using the after/time.sleep to update the treeview, but it is not working with the mainloop.

My questions are:

- How can I update the treeview widget with real-time data?
- And is there a way that I can change all treeview children simultaneously? (I don't want to delete all children and insert again)

Script 1:

```
class mainwindow(tk.Tk):
    #Initalize main window
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

       #use to shift frames
       ....
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    app = mainwindow()
    app.geometry("1920x1080")
    app.mainloop()
```

Script 2:

```
class Page_one(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        mainframe=tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        #treeview widget attached to page_one
        tree1=Treeviews(...)
        tree1.place(x=880,y=25)

#Question1: How can I update the treeview widget with real-time data? 
#Question2: is there a way that I can change all treeview children simuteniously? (I dont want to delete all children and insert again)
```

My question is: may someone show me a structure that I could use for updating widgets in my second script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify a treeview widget with the `item` method:

```
tree.item(<item id>, text='new text', values=(...))
```

The item's id is returned upon item creation. And you can change all the treeview children by putting the above code in a for loop:

```
for item in tree.get_children(<parent>):
    tree.item(item, text='new text', values=(...))
```

`tree.get_children(<parent>)` returns the children of the item  ('' for the root of the tree).

From your question, I understand that you have some separate process that generates data and you want to periodically update the treeview content with the new data generated. Using `time.sleep` would freeze the mainloop, so you should use the `after` tkinter method: `tree.after(<time in ms>, callback, *args)` will wait for the given time and then execute `callback(*args)`. If you want a periodical callback, the trick is to call again `after` inside `callback`, e.g.:

```
def callback(x, y):
    # do something with x and y ...
    tree.after(2000, callback, x, y)
```

So once you launch `callback(0, 2)`, it will be executed every 2s.

Here is an example with a treeview:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def update_item(item):
    val = int(tree.item(item, 'value')[0])
    tree.item(item, values=(val + 1,))
    root.after(1000, update_item, item)

def update_all_items():
    for item in tree.get_children():
        tree.item(item, values=(0,))

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=('value'))
tree.heading('value', text='Value')

for i in range(5):
    tree.insert('', 'end', 'item%i' % i, text='item %i' % i, values=(i,))

update_item('item0')

tree.pack()
ttk.Button(root, text='Update', command=update_all_items).pack()

root.mainloop()
```