# Updating tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I wrote a code to display a table using tkinter ttk Treeview.
Then, I selected one of the item on the table, and made a change on its item.
So, I updated the table by deleting all of its items and inserting a new ones.
But why were the items still referring to old table's item added by new ones?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win=tk.Tk()
def testcommand():

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        print(i)

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        tabel.delete(i)
    for i in tes:
        tabel.insert('', 'end', text=str(i))

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        print(i)
tabel=ttk.Treeview(win,selectmode='browse')
tabel.heading('#0',text="COBA")
tes=[1,2,3,4]
for i in tes:
    tabel.insert('','end',text=str(i))
tabel.pack()
ttk.Button(win,text='Test',command=testcommand).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

In the first 'print' statement, I got ('I001','I002','I003','I004') items, but after I updated my treeview, the item continued to ('I005','I006','I007','I008').

Why the 'delete method' from treeview didn't reset the item back to 'I001'?
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Alternativ: [update-with-real-time-data-in-tkinter-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437232/widget-in-sub-window-update-with-real-time-data-in-tkinter-python)

Comment: I don't see how you could make a change to an item in the list, they are fixed strings and cannot be edited while the program is running. Rather than focusing on what is currently happening, what is it that you are trying to achieve? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: It's just that I have made a lot of change of my data table, and I want to update it on Treeview the easy way by update it all at once, instead of changing it values one by one.

Comment: By the way, if you are unhappy with tkinter's default name for the items, you can name them yourself: `tree.insert('', 'end', 'item%i' % i, text=str(i))`.

Comment: thank you j_4321.  it's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter default names for the items of a treeview are 'I001', 'I002', ... and the counter used to create the names is not reset when all items are deleted from the treeview.

If one wants to reset the item names, they have to explicitly name the items themselves when creating them:

```
tree.insert('', 'end', <name>, **kw)
```

Adapting the OP's code, it gives

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win=tk.Tk()
def testcommand():

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        print(i)

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        tabel.delete(i)
    for i in tes:
        tabel.insert('', 'end', 'item%i' % i, text=str(i)) # explicitly name the item

    for i in tabel.get_children():
        print(i)
tabel=ttk.Treeview(win,selectmode='browse')
tabel.heading('#0',text="COBA")
tes=[1,2,3,4]
for i in tes:
    tabel.insert('','end', 'item%i' % i, text=str(i))  # explicitly name the item
tabel.pack()
ttk.Button(win,text='Test',command=testcommand).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

And the output when clicking on the test button is

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

as expected by the OP.